# Repeated log : Warn Transport Connection to tcp:<ip> failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: activemq-classic

I am running ActiveMQ 5.9.0 release on my local machine for dev purposes (Windows 7). I am using AMQP as the protocol and  Apache qpid as the client to consume messages (publish subscribe) from activeMQ broker (AMQP 1.0 protocol).

Although I have commented out all the protocols except `amqp` in `activemq.xml`, still periodically I am seeing the below message in broker log (standard out):

```
WARN: Transport Connect to tcp://<ip> failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

I did try to "uncomment" the openwire protocl definition in `activemq.xml` and append `transport.useInactivityMonitor=false` (based on googling around):

I still cannot get warning messages to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself.  But the amqp protocol is using the tcp transport under the covers.  Use of the protocol is documented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html).  You can configure it to use nio as well.  It is [hardcoded](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=activemq.git;a=blob;f=activemq-amqp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/AmqpTransportFactory.java;h=3cf72c995077b85b8ddd031d9083bc8f43952a08;hb=trunk) to have `useInactivityMonitor=false`.  You can modify the transport options on the amqp transport by setting those options in the connect uri.  For example:

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?transport.keepAlive=true"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

The tcp transport options are documented [here](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html).